# How to check HAX is working for the Virtual Device

Tags: android, haxm

I am trying to use `HAXM` method to create a virtual Device for Android programs testing. But as per the procedure I am not able to see the message that **HAXM is working** for that device. Although the device responds a bit faster but still I want to know that if I am missing something or not. Does the message is optional or any other problem exists?

I have checked that my system has Virtualization and its enabled from the BIOS. I also have installed the missing **PCI controller driver from the OEM**.

Answer (score 0):

You can see only when you start your AVD. I mean when your AVD boots up, it shows the message on the message screen which says **"HAX is working and emulator runs in....."** .

I've attached a screen-shot of the message it shows while my AVD NexusS_AVD19 booting up. You can observe the same while your AVD is booting up as well

[image: HAX indicating image]

There are so specific settings for this screen to appear. But as per my detailed observation, this might be due to your Antivirus and how much resources it takes because I've tested it myself.

What I observed is: Earlier I had Malware antivirus in my system and the above screen shot was appearing normally, But on some days, I installed avast antivirus as well in my system and with that I could not see the above details showing up. I was wondering what caused HAZM message to disappear and realized that it could be cause of resources consumption by the antivirus. I searched all over the net how does Avast actually functions :)

Then, I unintalled Avast and made Malware back again, and was able to see the screenshot as usual.  To confirm my observation, I repeated the steps couple of times and it was clearly visible for me the difference.

So, to keep shot, If your antivirus consumes too many resources, you might not see the HAXM message on the screen cause by the time it comes up your AVD screen boots up and the other screen goes to background.

This is a bit weird but it is true and I tried couple of times on my Desktop as well as Laptop and the analysis worked as I explained above.

Comment: I can see only the first line as **Starting emulator for AVD_Nexus_by_Google**.
Rest of the lines are not displayed which is the cause of my concern. Please tell me the way around.

Comment: Please check my answer as I edited it again. As my wording is more than 350+, I had to respond in an answer.

Comment: @ApoorvRastogi - Please accept it answer and vote up such that you encourage newbies like me to help further to others as well by doing it for myself and learning...